# Binding form elements to new objects in angular using ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs

In the controller I get around 200 episodes, some containing an actor object:

```
$http.get('/episodes.json').success(function(data) {
  $scope.episodes = data;
});
```

In the view I display the actors, and I have inputs to edit their names:

`.actor{ng_repeat:"actor in episode.actors"}`

```
  .actor-name
    %a
     {{actor.first_name}} {{actor.last_name}}
  .actor-input
    %input{type: 'text', ng_model:"actor.first_name"}
    %input{type: 'text', ng_model:"actor.last_name"}
```

After each set of actors, I want to have an empty field to add a new actor to the episode.

- Jon Benjamin
- Judy Greer
- [ *First Name* ] [ *Last Name* ] **Add Actor +**

---

What is the best way to bind a blank `actor` to add to the current `episode.actors` object?

The end goal is to submit with `$http`, save the actor to the DB, then on `success` display the actor in the list with a new blank `actor` field.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you should change your model to add a "special" member to work as placeholder.

I'd rather have the `.actor{ng-repeat:...` and you simply add the empty actor input field after this guy.

Your code will be simpler and you will avoid the complexity of treating the special case for when the actor is not yet persisted.

Comment: Sorry I don't know how exactly to ask the question.  Imagine the sample angular todo app.  The input has ng-model="todoText"

Now imagine 200 'ToDo lists' on one page, each with an input to add a new ToDo.  But each one is still bound to the same model.